# JavaScript Add Top or margin-top to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add top to class based on div height:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    var offsetHeight = $(test).height(); //Successfully Got height   
    var txt = "Height with padding and border: " + offsetHeight + "px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("logo_helper").style.top = txt;
});
```

And i get such error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>
```

I'm not very strong at JS. Can someone help?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("logo_helper")[?]

Comment: The the linked question's answers. `getElementsByClassName` returns a *list* of elements. To access elements in the list, you need to index into it (`[0]`, `[1]`, etc.) and then you can use `.style` on the elements. Alternately, add a new `style` element to `head` with a rule for the class so you don't have to handle each element individually.